# Springframework cron expression for 2 different time slots

Tags: spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I am trying to use spring-framework for scheduling. I need to schedule job everyday 2:00 am and 8:30 am. Since minute part is varying wondering how to write accurate cron expression.

I tried following -

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0,30 2,8 * * *")
```

But thats quite not I want. Wondering if it is possible to have expression for my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. Presently not possible so end up creating 2 jobs performing same operation but scheduled at different times i.e. 2:00 am and 8:30 am.